# How to turn off USB-C charging while my HP ProBook 445 G7 is off?

Tags: laptop, battery, power, usb-c, hp

On my  HP ProBook 445 G7 I disabled quick boot in Windows, wake up on LAN and USB are also disabled in BIOS but the battery looses about 14% a week when it's shut down.

When I connect my phone to the USB C port it starts charging when the laptop is off. It doesn't happen with USB A ports.

I saw posts for other laptops having a BIOS option to turn USB charging off but I cannot find it in my BIOS.

How do I disable the USB C charging while the laptop is off?

Comment: Seems like you are approaching this as an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/243319) when you say this, “…but the battery looses about 14% a week when it's shut down.” I don’t think disabling the USB C port would solve the loss of battery power issue.

Comment: @Giacomo1968, maybe, but the USB charging circuitry is the only obvious thing that I see drawing power while off, I could be wrong of course.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I disable the USB-C charging while the laptop is off?

I have that kind of setup on my Lenovo Laptop.

Two solutions:

(A) Turn it OFF in BIOS.

(B) More preferable:  Do not use the port when the machine is turned off unless it is plugged in. I use Battery Threshold, so the very best solution is to use this port when the machine is running.  This works best for me.

Note that I use Battery Threshold to allow me to worked plugged in all the time. But if I turn OFF, then I unplug the machine.

It is also possible your battery may lose charge when idle, so consider that possibility.

Comment: B - I don't have anything plugged in but it still looses charge at about 14% per week, I'm not using the laptop very often so it would loose all charge after a couple of months off.

Comment: How does Battery Threshold help here? (I'm assuming it's the same as HP's Battery Care where it won't charge to above 80%? I have it enabled.)

Comment: If nothing is plugged in (a) try turning off the port and (b) look for another cause.  The battery itself may lose some charge when idle.  Battery Threshold comment was just to say I do not leave it plugged in when off.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try disable the port in BIOS. I don't think it's just battery self discharge, it's too much, it's supposed to be 5% per month for li-po batteries.

Comment: Tried disabling all USB ports in BIOS but it doesn't have any effect anywhere, power still available on the USB-C port when off and all ports are working as usual in windows. Will see if it helps with the battery drain in case it's not because of the power on the USB-C port.