# HP Probook 445 G7: Reduce battery drain while off

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown, hp

This is related to my other question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1722346/how-to-turn-off-usb-c-charging-while-my-hp-probook-445-g7-is-off).

I've a new HP Probook 445 G7 bought in March 2022 which is sitting off most of the time. It's loosing about 10-15% of battery per week while off. I've heard that this can be around 2% per week for other laptops so I think it's too high.

I've battery care on if it matters (my understanding is that it's just limiting the maximum charge to 80% and changing the battery charge indication proportionately so that it's 100%).

I've disable Quick boot in Windows and disabled USB devices in BIOS (they are still working fine so I'm not sure what it does) but it didn't help.

I've noticed that I can charge my phone from the laptop's USB-C port when the laptop is off, not sure if it's the cause of the drain or not. (it won't charge from USB-A ports though).
I've tried looking for a BIOS option to disable USB charging when the laptop is off but haven't found anything (presumably some laptops have such an option).

How do I fix the quick battery drain while the laptop is off?

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably, this seems to be a problem for many brands of laptops. After checking an HP laptop for everything from BIOS settings and OS settings to anti-theft background processes (location, WiFi pinging, etc.), I believe the issue may be due to *Li cell-balancing hardware* in the internal charging circuit.

For that particular laptop, with a *removable* battery, the fix was simple: remove the battery when the laptop will not be used for more than a few weeks. Loss of charge dropped from ~10% week to ~2%/week. It is worthwhile doing so, because of the danger of discharging the battery to the point where it is damaged and can no longer be recharged. BTW, the internal clock did *not* lose time, since it runs from a separate cell.

That said, for a laptop with *internal* battery, this would not be a trivial solution, because it would require installing a *multiple-pole switch* to the battery, because there are connections to *each cell* of the battery for load balancing. A 4PST (four-pole, single-throw) or 4PDT (four-pole, double-throw, with one set of contacts unused) switch, for example these [from AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3256803188460040.html) or [from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00T1DCM58), is needed for a three-cell, ~10 volt, battery. It would need to be installed by **someone understanding of electronic circuitry and capable of hardware modification**, permanently modifying the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you PC is in hibernation mode?
And ofcourse if you could charge with it, it will definitely drain the battery.
Secondly, if you sure the oc is properly shut down, it's possible the power button may have some problems. Then your best bet is to have a technician check it out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's not in hibernate for sure. I don't see any issues with the power button, it would not power on/off if this was the case.